char* vs std::string.data()
I'm using a Azure IoT Hub to send and receive messages to and from a device. To do this, I'm utilizing a library written in C and my application is written in C++. When I convert my std::string to a char* with the data() function to send a message with the C library, the start of the text gets mangled when I receive it in the hub.
The library's send function expects a struct like this when sending a message from the device to the cloud:
struct azure_iot_hub_buf {
    /* Pointer to buffer. */
    char *ptr;

    /* Size of buffer. */
    size_t size;
};

Defining the message like this:
char* message = "\"This is a long test string to test the functionality\"";
struct azure_iot_hub_buf payload;
payload.ptr = message;
payload.size = strlen(message);

seems to work, when testing in my Azure hub I receive this message:

However, the message I'm sending is not static and is of type std::string so I would like to define it like this:
std::string message = get_message(); // Gets some string message
result.ptr = message.data();
result.size = message.size();


but when I receive the message in Azure IoT Hub the start of the text gets mangled:

Looking at this, I thought that I must be doing something wrong, the message I'm sending is obviously getting altered when I'm assigning it so I debugged my firmware found the raw memory of the variable right before sending the message:

But it seems like the messages are identical. The only difference I can see, is that the char* is allocated on the stack as it is defined compile time, while the std::string is allocated in RAM as it is defined at runtime. Could this cause any problems I'm not aware of?

message.data() becomes invalid once the message changes size or destructs.

But the message does not change size or destructs, it is declared right before sending it in the same scope. This: https://i.sstatic.net/LRp9T7Rd.png is the raw memory from a debug session at the time of sending the data with both methods.

You posted so little code it wasn't clear what the lifetime of message is. From the mangled text, it sure looks like the memory was freed prematurely. You can set a write breakpoint to see who is corrupting the memory. My money is still on either a size change or a reallocation (or a reassignment).

@Nils Rasmussen The std::string::data() function returns a pointer to the internal buffer of the std::string object. This buffer is valid as long as the std::string object is not modified or destroyed.
Ensure that the std::string object remains in scope and unmodified while the
char* pointer is being used.

std::string message = get_message();
char* ptr = const_cast<char*>(message.c_str());
std::cout << "Address of ptr: " << static_cast<void*>(ptr) << std::endl;
payload.ptr = ptr;
payload.size = message.size();
// Set a write breakpoint on ptr's address and run the code
send_to_hub(payload);
// Possible modification or reassignment
message = "Another message";  // This could potentially reallocate memory

"Thank you all, you were right—the string was indeed being destructed during transmission. I hadn't been careful about where the string was created. Moving the string's initialization resolved the issue."

The error you are encountering is due to the memory for the std::string being altered or invalidated while it was being used.
The issue was resolved by adjusting the string's initialization.

I followed this GitHub repository for sending and receiving messages using Azure IoT.

std::string message = get_message();
size_t message_size = message.size();
char* buffer = new char[message_size + 1];
std::memcpy(buffer, message.data(), message_size);
buffer[message_size] = '\0'; // Null-terminate if needed

struct azure_iot_hub_buf payload;
payload.ptr = buffer;
payload.size = message_size;

// Use the payload
send_to_hub(payload);

// Clean up
delete[] buffer;


std::string messageContent(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(buffer), size); std::cout << "Received message: " << messageContent << std::endl;


Output:

